# build error while using ng build

Tags: angular, angular2-cli

I getting this error:
"You have to be inside an angular-cli project in order to use the build command" after creating a new angular2 app from the CLI.
I'm inside the project dir and I don't understand the meaning of the error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `cd` into that newly created directory.

```
cd DIRECTORY_NAME_HERE
```

Then you can do:

```
ng build 
ng serve 
// etc
```

Comment: well, that's what I did.
Anyway, now it seems to be working but I don't know why.

Comment: You might of just somehow changed directory, the cli will prompt that when it's the case. Strange, at least it worked :)